# What pH indicators are commonly used for non-polar medium?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, ph, solvents

Compounds, commonly used as [pH-indicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH_indicator), are soluble in aqueous media and polar solvents (DMSO, DMF, NMP etc.) and are functional pretty much across all these solvents. However, practically none these indicators are soluble in non-polar solvents (hexane, chloroform, dioxane etc.).

I briefly searched for the suitable available systems and so far there is only an article about oxoporphyrinogen derivatives used as pH-indicators in $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ [1]. Are there any other *common* substances that are typically used for the visualization of acid-base equilibrium in solvents with low polarity?

#### Reference

1. Shundo, A.; Ishihara, S.; Labuta, J.; Onuma, Y.; Sakai, H.; Abe, M.; Ariga, K.; Hill, J. P. *Chem. Commun.* **2013,** *49* (61), 6870–6872. [DOI: 10.1039/C3CC42859A](https://doi.org/10.1039/C3CC42859A).

Comment: pH does not really make sense outside of aquaeous solutions, so~

Comment: I disagree with @Jan's comment a bit. The notational definition of pH isn't specific to water. Relative activity of a proton is equally well/poorly defined in non-aqueous solvents. Comparing them is difficult because of different reference points. There are proposed solutions (e.g., a unified acidity scale), and this has been realised experimentally for HPLC liquid phases. That said, I don't see a straight-forward way of comparing pH across solvents via a colour indicator. If this is not a problem, five titration indicators are apparently listed [here](https://goo.gl/PcdPuJ). (not a sci paper)

Comment: (ref-s for previous comment: [doi: 10.1002/anie.201000252](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201000252), [doi: 10.1021/ac504692m](https://doi.org/10.1021/ac504692m))

Comment: @Jan, pH+ is quite sensible for Lewis and for Bronsted-Lowery acids-bases in non-aqueous media.

Comment: @LinearChristmas Of course, scales and definitions exist; see for example the DMSO $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values in the Bordwell data. But the thing is that when one sees ‘pH’, the layman assumes 7 being neutral and the scale essentially going from 1 to 14 which is only true in water. Of course, protons are still acidic outside aquaeous solution and certain solvents can accept them in acid-base reactions (or donate their own). I think this shouldn’t be called ‘pH’ though.

Comment: True, pH+ is associated with aqueous solutions in most people's minds. BTW, 7 is neutral only at ~300 K. At boiling, 373 K, neutral's ~6.14.